# How to get DynamoDB table tags

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk-js

I want to use the @aws-sdk/client-dynamodb or @aws-sdk/lib-dynamodb modules to be able to retrieve DynamoDB table tags from NodeJS

I have a lambda function listening for changes in a DynamoDB table, an item can have a bunch of columns but I want to dynamically specify the columns I am interested in to listen for changes. I was thinking about using tags as I didn't find any other way to specify information like that. For Example, let's say the table is:

```
Table Name: People
Columns: id, name, last_name, nationality, profession
Tag: field_names=name,profession
```

In this case, I would change the tag value to add/remove more columns if I need to

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `listTagsOfResource` method to get all tags on an Amazon DynamoDB resource.

```
var params = {
  ResourceArn: 'STRING_VALUE', /* required */
  NextToken: 'STRING_VALUE'
};
dynamodb.listTagsOfResource(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

`ResourceArn`:- The Amazon DynamoDB resource with tags to be listed. This value is an Amazon Resource Name (ARN). In your case, value will be the ARN of the DynamoDB table - *people* something like this:- `arn:aws:dynamodb:us-west-2:123456789012:table/people`